# window.print() not working in IE 11 using react.js with react-pdf library

Tags: reactjs

window.print() doesn't seem to work in IE. I am using react.js with react-pdf library being used.

Below is my sample code:

```
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf/build/entry.noworker";

class PrintFile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    window.print();
  }

  render() {
    const {
      pdfFile,
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <DocumentTitle title={pdfFile.name}>
        <div id="printable">
          <Document
            file={pdfFile}
          >
            ...
          </Document>
        </div>
      </DocumentTitle>
    );
  }
}

PrintFile.propTypes = {
    pdfFile: PropTypes.object,
};

export default PrintFile;
```

I have removed the logic and just put the basic stuff required here..

[PDF Library Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf)

Comment: Calling print in componentDidUpdate? Please dont use libs that override native functions like window.print().

Comment: @Sulthan whats the alternate ?